# Происхождение выражения "шут гороховый"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение, и почему шут именно гороховый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В старину на святки совершались обрады вокруг чучела, окутанного гороховой соломой. Также этой соломой опутывали себя скоморохи.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему шут гороховый?
>
> Потому что атрибутом средневековых шутов была гороховая погремушка
>
> Шут был одним из персонажей в европейском средневековом театре. Он носил полосатый желто-зеленый костюм, на голове шапочку с ослиными ушами, а в руке держал погремушку — палочку с привязанным к ней бычьим пузырем, в который насыпали горох. (Кстати, от упомянутого двуцветного костюма пошло зафиксированное в словаре Даля выражение «шут полосатый».) Свое появление на публике шут всегда предварял звуком этой погремушки, а во время представления колотил ею других персонажей и даже зрителей. Импровизированные шутовские монологи называли «толченым горохом», а погремушка выступала в этих репризах в роли фаллического символа — своего рода орудием посрамления. Да и сам горох, считавшийся у древних символом плодородия, также ассоциировался с телесным низом. Гороховый бубенец был принадлежностью паяцев еще в Древнем Риме. У латинян его позаимствовали византийцы, тогда как в самом Риме эта традиция была утрачена. Лишь во время Крестовых походов погремушка вернулась с Ближнего Востока в Европу и впоследствии добралась до Руси. Русские скоморохи также украшали себя гороховой соломой, а в конце Масленицы соломенное чучело шута горохового возили по улицам.

http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/quiz/687/